# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.ListBlobsOptions

Tags: java, azure, java-11, azure-blob-storage, pcf

I'm trying to connect to Azure Blob Storage to retrieve files that were already stored in blob storage. This works perfectly fine when I compile and run it in local. But when I deploy the application in PCF cloud, it does not work. See the error below.

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]
   2019-08-07T15:15:22.22-0400 [RTR/8] OUT mapgenerator.apps.pp01.useast.cf.ford.com - [2019-08-07T19:15:22.175+0000] "GET /api/v1/downloadTiles HTTP/1.1" 500 0 302 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36" "10.224.32.35:32828" "10.224.32.109:61058" x_forwarded_for:"136.2.17.160, 10.224.32.35" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"a0490649-6901-4943-793e-adde2bbe2c48" response_time:0.053182431 app_id:"45020c95-1730-4f21-8f97-7fa0cc67c7ff" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"7969216829b7dbdc" x_b3_spanid:"7969216829b7dbdc" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
   2019-08-07T15:15:22.22-0400 [RTR/8] OUT 
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Before Initializing ListBlobsOptions
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [ERROR] ExceptionLoggingFilter - Uncaught exception thrown <org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.ListBlobsOptions>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.ListBlobsOptions
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1006)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:48)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:86)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.cloudfoundry.router.ClientCertificateMapper.doFilter(ClientCertificateMapper.java:77)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:677)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.ListBlobsOptions
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at com.ford.cbz.map.generator.MapGenerator.listBlobs(MapGenerator.java:67)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at com.ford.cbz.map.generator.MapController.getBlob(MapController.java:18)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
   2019-08-07T15:16:23.50-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     ... 53 more
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52913597/springboot-org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-get-constructor-for-org-hi

Comment: I am running this on JDK11 in both local & PCF. Does it still need java assist dependency? @NgSharma

Comment: yes. It is still need, if you using java 11.

Comment: Did not make any difference even after adding the java assist dependency. @NgSharma

Comment: https://medium.com/criciumadev/its-time-migrating-to-java-11-5eb3868354f9