# Spring boot deploy: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I try deploy my spring boot web application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I saw full logs and there is stack trace like below, but when I run mvn clean package in Intellij idea terminal I get the same errors like below.

I was using **'mvn clean package -DskipTests'** to now and command wasn't finish broke result. There was no errors in terminal, but when I use this command without -DskipTests stack trace error is like below:

Can you tell me why I get this error ? How resolve this problem ?

On The other band, what can cause this error with entitymanagerfactory ? I checked conflicts in pom.xml and There was conflicts between httpclient nad httpcore, I removed this dependencies but error still  occur. Any idea?

I searched in other stackoverflow topics and I didn't find any solution. Nothing worked.
I know from other post in stackoverflow that test class don't want to compile. I don't know why.

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>social-simple</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>social-simple</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>[4.0,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   SocialApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationC...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.753 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-29T21:22:42+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project social-simple: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/huber/Pulpit/divelog/target/surefire-reports for the 
individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream 
and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the 
following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

2019-11-29 21:22:41.830 ERROR 32048 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@76494737] to prepare test instance [com.example.SocialApplicationTests@70485aa]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

My application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/divelog
spring.datasource.username=divelog
spring.datasource.password=divelog
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hiberrnate.dialect= 
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect

server.port=5000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

UPDATE - RESOLVED

I was following with this AWS tutorial and everything works perfectly. I had to connect security groups RDS and Elastic Beanstalk.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html

Comment: Go through this link and troubleshoot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058001/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-class-path-resou

Comment: See this answer that has to do with javaassist. You are missing a jar file or setter method: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
</dependency> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058001/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-class-path-resou

Comment: I added javassist dependency and column annotation on each field in entities and mvn clean package works fine, but I still get this error on AWS logs when deploy me web app. I get too JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution. I changed property driver-class-name to driverClassName but still errors are the same. The credentials for database are good because I'm still connected to AWS Database by pgAdmin 4.

Answer (score 2):

This error is related to your JPA means your database connection is creating some trouble. Please check the configuration for your DB mentioned in properties file and also, check your entities as well if anything is wrong with them.
Also, share application.properties file here as well for better understanding.

Comment: I commented all relationships in my entities, I didn't comment Entity, Id and GeneratedValue annotations. All repositories turned of from Repository annotation and nothing change. Error still occurs. I updated post to my application.properties content file.

Comment: Follow the link below, add mentioned dependancy in you pom.xml. This error is totally depend on your DB connection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52913597/springboot-org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-get-constructor-for-org-hi

Comment: Maven command works after add this dependency. I'm connected to database in AWS with my pgAdmin4, so data and credentials works fine, but when I want connect application in Elastic Beanstalk I get error 'unable to connect jdbc connection for ddl execution'. Maybe I don't have good configuration in AWS?